# interpreting BLE device using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth

Hi I have one BLE device which has TI CC2541 chip and some sensors. I want to create my own iOS app using swift.

Currently, using the [lightBlue](https://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCIQFjAAahUKEwj2r5PHpeLGAhWMEywKHYYpAY0&url=https%3A%2F%2Fitunes.apple.com%2Fen%2Fapp%2Flightblue-bluetooth-low-energy%2Fid557428110%3Fmt%3D8&ei=EgapVfbeEoynsAGG04ToCA&usg=AFQjCNFy01YddTEpda8gx1cUMfsdLVn61g&sig2=LQy-vvqet0DgTTAJAGQJIA&bvm=bv.97949915,d.bGg) App, I can see following services and characteristics:

1) Device Information
2) UUID: FFF0

1. Characteristics 1, properties: read, write, UUID: FFF1
2. Characteristics 2, properties: read, UUID: FFF2
3. Characteristics 3, properties: write, UUID: FFF3
4. Characteristics 4, properties: Notify, UUID: FFF4
5. Characteristics 5, properties: read, UUID: FFF5

3) UUID: FFE0

1. Key Press State A, properties Write Notify, UUID: FFE1
2. Key Press State B, properties Write, UUID: FFE2
3. Key Press State C, properties Write Notify, UUID: FFE3

I could figure out that everytime I press a button on a device, the FFE1 (Key Press State A) returns a 9-byte values, as following:

<0e0a1f0f 271e000d 01> --> [2574, 3871, 7719, 11264, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
<0e0a1f0f 271e002c 01> --> [2574, 3871, 7719, 3328, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]

Question: I am not able to understand this values? What these value represents? I would appreciate your feedback to get started.

Comment: That data is specific to the device, there's no set format it's just a set of bytes. Have a look for documentation for your chip.

Comment: (Side note: those aren't bytes as the maximum byte value is 255)

Comment: Thanks for the reply! You are right, they are not byte values.